# updating found set with radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Context is a check-out process, where a user can pick from her/his shipping addresses.  Thus a controller action states:

```
@shipping_addresses = ShippingAddress.where(['user_id = ?',  current_user.id])
```

I find it more appealing to have a boolean value for preferred so that when the check-out process is repeated by the user, s/he is presented with the preferred address.  But the question lies in changing this preferred attribute.

In short, a radio button needs to be created to set preferred to true in a form (is there anyway to have on selected, deslecting the other ones?) and then the form needs to  update records

```
  def update_preferred
    respond_to do |format|
    if @shipping_addresses.save
    @shipping_addresses = ShippingAddress.where(['user_id = ?',  current_user.id]).update_all("preferred = 'false'")
    -- selected_shipping_address.update("preferred = 'true'")
  end
```

..also having a hard time with the syntax for declaring the form (as I've never steered away from the standard rails conventions...):

```
<%= form_for(@shipping_addresses) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

One working solution.  In the form, include the radio button, which allows only one selection to the user:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "shipping_address_id", shipping_address.id %>
<%= submit_tag "update" %>
```

with the defined route to the action, include the method in the controller, which first sets all the found set to false, then the selected shipping_address to true.

```
  def update_preferred
    @shipping_address = ShippingAddress.find(params[:shipping_address_id])
    @shipping_addresses = ShippingAddress.where(['user_id = ?',  current_user.id]).update_all("preferred = 'false'")
    @shipping_address.update_column(:preferred, "true")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shipping_address.update_attributes(params[:shipping_address])
        format.html { redirect_to cart_url(session[:cart_id]), notice: 'Shipping address was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to cart_url(session[:cart_id]), notice: 'Shipping address was not updated.' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Maybe this can be simplified more.  Comments welcome.